# --Store DOM elements that I use in React so I don't keep pulling them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, dom, view

This is for both regular DOM elements and jQuery elements.  I want the actual elements to be stored some where in the class.  Is there a reference to a common pattern for doing this?

Also, I'm aware that in general you should not use jQuery with React but I need the jQuery functions to make my menu work and don't have time for a refactor but it works fine.

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

class MobileMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.clickHandler1 = this.clickHandler1.bind(this);
    this.clickHandler2 = this.clickHandler2.bind(this);
    this.clickHandler3 = this.clickHandler3.bind(this);
  }

  clickHandler1 () {
    this.toggleMenu();
  }

  clickHandler2 () {
    // MenuPage.flip('fave');
    this.toggleMenu();
    this.toggleMarker($A.el('#nav_fave'));
  }

  clickHandler3 () {
    // MenuPage.flip('splash');
    this.toggleMenu();
    this.toggleMarker($A.el('#nav_splash'));
  }

  toggleMarker (current_item) {
    if ((this.previous_item !== undefined) && (this.previous_item !== current_item)) {
        this.previous_item.style.borderBottom = '';
    }
    if (this.previous_item !== current_item) {
        current_item.style.borderBottom = '3px solid #31baed';
    }
    this.previous_item = current_item;
  }

  toggleMenu () {
    if (window.getComputedStyle($A.el('#top_menu_list'), null).display === 'block') {
        $('#icon_bars').toggleClass('active');
        $('#top_menu').slideToggle();
    }
  }
  // ... snip
}

export default MobileMenu
```

Comment: What does "the actual elements to be stored some where in the class" mean?  What do you mean by "pulling them"?

Comment: Once I do this ... `let store = $('#icon_bars')` I want to store that result somewhere.  I could just put it on this like `this.store = store`, but I was wondering if there is a common pattern/approach/idiom developers use?

Comment: theres no common pattern to this as this is an anti pattern to react

Comment: you can use whats called refs in react. You also want to be really careful when using JQuery and react as they can step on on each other's toes. Unless you absolutely have to have JQuery for something you will save yourself a lot of heartache by just not using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the `ref` [pattern](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).
Keep in mind that you are using react the wrong way, one of its best features is the super fast rendering due to the virtual `DOM` and [Diff](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#the-diffing-algorithm) algorithm.
**Which you are ruing!!!** :)

**EDIT as a followup to your comment**
The `ref` attribute will allow you to add an object to your react component `class`, this object is a reference to the actual `DOM` element.
So basically you can wrap it with a `jQuery` method and do whatever you need.
With That being said, again i really advice against that!
An example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  
  this.changeColor = this.changeColor.bind(this);
}

  changeColor(e){
    $(this.myelement).addClass('highlight');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Do not use jQuery with React!</h3>
        <div ref={(el) => {this.myelement = el}} onClick={this.changeColor}>
        Click me!
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.highlight {
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  background: #333;
  color: #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

**EDIT #2**
You are now asking how to modify elements (adding a `css` class for example) in react.
Well this is entirely a different question which i'm sure there are several good answers on SO, but i will give you a small example anyway.
I'm using the same code as the example above but now i'm doing it without `jQuery`.
As for `css` and styling in general with react i urge you to read about the different approaches which i won't explain here ([css modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules), [styled components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) etc..).
Keep in mind that this is a really small and simple example and i used 1 of many patterns out there to tackle this challenge.

```js
const MyComponent = ({highlight, onClick}) => {
  const cssClassName = highlight && 'highlight'; // this will be undefined or 'highlight'
  return(
    <div className={cssClassName} onClick={onClick} >Click me for a COMPONENT example!</div>
  );
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isDivClicked: false,
      isComponentClicked: false
    }
    this.changeDiv = this.changeDiv.bind(this);
    this.changeComponent = this.changeComponent.bind(this);
  }

  changeDiv(e){
    this.setState({isDivClicked: true});
  }
  
  changeComponent(e){
    this.setState({isComponentClicked: true});
  }
  
  render() {
    const {isDivClicked, isComponentClicked} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Do not use jQuery with React!</h3>
        <div onClick={this.changeDiv} className={isDivClicked && 'highlight'}>
          Click me for a simple DIV example!
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <MyComponent onClick={this.changeComponent} highlight={isComponentClicked}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.highlight {
  display:inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  background: #333;
  color: #ccc;
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Agreed that the OP's specific example is not a good use for `ref` but your answer somewhat implies that React's diffing system makes this pattern unnecessary in all cases, which is not true. The best example I can cite is transformations. If you wanted to mouse drag an element around the page, you need to update its transform style many dozens of times per second. That many renders will have a significant performance impact vs. updating the elmeent's `style.transform` property directly. I know from experience making an HTML5 PDF viewer that's responsive to multitouch gestures.

Answer (score -2):

Why not use a basic object array and push them by ID?

I created a simple demo.  Maybe there is a more elegant way to do this with react, but using jquery as a helper this is pretty easy.

https://jsfiddle.net/cfnb4fkw/

```
var domCache = new Array();

function cacheDomObj(domObj){
     domCache[$(domObj).attr('id')] = domObj;
}

function getDomObj(id){
    return domCache[id];
}

function demo(){
    cacheDomObj($("#domElement1"));
    alert("Element cached" + domCache.length);
    $("#domElement1").remove();
    alert("Removed element");
    var retreivedElement = getDomObj('domElement1');
    $("#container").append(retreivedElement);
}

demo();
```

You could integrate this into your class and speed it up a little if you wanted to make cacheDomObj more verbose...

```
function cacheDomObj(id,obj){
      domCach[id] = obj;
}
```